# Javascript - Testing browser code on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

We have a node.js app that displays content on partner websites. Our partners include some javascript code in their HTML templates, pointing to our server, and we then use the URL of the page which loads our code to figure out what content to show. Being a third-party script, we mostly rely on document.referrer to get the URL of the including page, but sometimes we are included in an iframe, which complicates things. We are looking to make this code more robust by writing a comprehensive test suite.

Is there a good way to test this type of functionality on the server? We’d need to emulate a browser with javascript support, and it would need to report the referrer like a normal browser would. We’d also need to be able to test cross-origin issues on the server, by simulating domain names, ports etc.

It would be preferable to use node.js for this, but that’s not a requirement.

Comment: Seems like a rather inconsistent way to detect who is asking for the content?  Why not pass a hash or token of some sort in the query string of your script url to identify the client site?  That is what we do, this also enables the client to have multiple versions of our script on their pages.

Comment: Can you have the included JavaScript report the `window.top.location.href`? It's not infallible (obviously), but could be useful.

Comment: Why do you want the server of all the machines that could do the test? And yes, there are cross-browser test suites for such things. Have you tried any?

Comment: @box86rowh, we need to know the entire URL, not just the partner ID (since we have indexed the partner’s pages and need to pick the right one to use as the basis for our content), but we do in fact currently send the URL as a param when included in an iframe. If the most robust solution turns out to be sending the URL as a param, that’s fine with us.

Comment: @DavidThomas, that may indeed turn out to be the solution we end up with, depending on how robust it is. We wanted to start with a way to test this, before we get to work on the actual JS code. It’s not just about the URL, though, we also use different ways to inject our content, based on the method of integration. For example, we sometimes use document.write and other times we use DOM methods to add our content to an element that the partner specifies. We want to be able to test all these things.

Comment: @Bergi, it would be nice to change something on the server and then just run "node test" to make sure everything works as it should before deploying. But like I said, we are open to other solutions. We haven’t tried any test suites for these things.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant that you can run those testsuites on your server as everywhere else - if you want to call them from node.js, you can do so.